# Mod-Rewrite for dynamic URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my URLs to be more SEO friendly, and I'm doing this in my .htaccess file using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteRule blog/(.*)/$ blog/index.php?&link=$1 [NC]      
RewriteRule ^/*(.+/)?([^.]*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

That code allows me to rewrite http://example.com/blog/index.php?link=22 into http://example.com/blog/page-title/

The only problem here, is that I'm trying to get it to work without the ending slash (/). I've tried removing it in the third line of the .htaccess code (right fater the $2), but that just breaks everything and the rewrite doesn't work at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try now, both with or without slash should work.

```
RewriteEngine On      
RewriteRule blog/(.*)/?$ blog/index.php?&link=$1 [NC]      
RewriteRule ^/*(.+/)?([^.]*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I'm using this exact code:  

`RewriteRule demo/(.*)/?$ demo/index.php?&link=$1 [NC]        
RewriteRule ^/*(.+/)?([^.]*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/demo/$1$2/ [L,R=301]`
  
It automatically adds the slash (/) at the end, and now instead of loading the page it gives me a 404.